# how do i track state when there are multiple selections

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i have a scenario where a user has three options:

he can choose the **body_type** of a car, the **car_year** it was made, or the **car_make** of it.

starting out, i have a state `carJson` that is set to a list of cars.

```
"2": {
   "attrs": {
      "car_year": 2021,
      "car_make": "Volvo",
      "car_model": "XC60",
      "car_trim": "T8 Plug-In Hybrid Inscription Expression eAWD",
      "body_type": "SUV"
   }
},
"4": {
   "attrs": {
      "car_year": 2020,
      "car_make": "Honda",
      "car_model": "Fit",
      "car_trim": "LX Manual",
      "body_type": "hatchback"
   }
},
"5": {
   "attrs": {
      "car_year": 2020,
      "car_make": "Jeep",
      "car_model": "Renegade",
      "car_trim": "Trailhawk 4WD",
      "body_type": "SUV"
   }
},
"6": {
   "attrs": {
      "car_year": 2022,
      "car_make": "Kia",
      "car_model": "Forte",
      "car_trim": "FE Manual",
      "body_type": "sedan"
   }
},
```

if the user chooses the **body_type**, i have `setCarJson` update to only include cars that have a matching body type.

from there, the **car_year** and **car_make** options are updated to only show those filtered cars.  but the **body_type** options remain the same, so that the user can change his choice.

**so for example**, the user chooses 'SUV' - so the years available to select from will be {2020,2021}.  pretty straight forward.

**but now,** let's say the user chooses 2021.  the **make** should only show {volvo} and the car body_type choices shouldn't change.  so there should be three different states, right?

it could very well be that the user starts off with the make or the year, instead of the body type - so i want that first choice to offer the original options.

[image: diagram]

and finally to structure it so that let's say the user deselects **body_type** after choosing **car_year** - it will update to show only body_types that fall within that selected year.

**so basically,** three selections, that progressively/regressively filter each other out.

just looking for some kind of direction on how to think about this.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

https://react-wj8s1v.stackblitz.io/

In case that stack blitz doesn't work, here is my code

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {

  // Initial Data
  const cars = {
    2: {
      attrs: {
        car_year: 2021,
        car_make: 'Volvo',
        car_model: 'XC60',
        car_trim: 'T8 Plug-In Hybrid Inscription Expression eAWD',
        body_type: 'SUV',
      },
    },
    4: {
      attrs: {
        car_year: 2020,
        car_make: 'Honda',
        car_model: 'Fit',
        car_trim: 'LX Manual',
        body_type: 'hatchback',
      },
    },
    5: {
      attrs: {
        car_year: 2020,
        car_make: 'Jeep',
        car_model: 'Renegade',
        car_trim: 'Trailhawk 4WD',
        body_type: 'SUV',
      },
    },
    6: {
      attrs: {
        car_year: 2022,
        car_make: 'Kia',
        car_model: 'Forte',
        car_trim: 'FE Manual',
        body_type: 'sedan',
      },
    },
  };

  // state to house our new filtered option
  const [filteredCars, setFilteredCars] = useState(cars);
  
  // all of our cars
  const carIndexes = Object.keys(filteredCars);
  
  // create select options for make, year, and body
  const bodySelects = () => {
    const bodies = [];
    carIndexes.forEach((index) => {
      bodies.push(filteredCars[index].attrs.body_type);
    });
    return bodies.map((x, y) => <option key={y}>{x}</option>);
  };

  const yearSelects = () => {
    const years = [];
    carIndexes.forEach((index) => {
      years.push(filteredCars[index].attrs.car_year);
    });
    return years.map((x, y) => <option key={y}>{x}</option>);
  };

  const makeSelects = () => {
    const makes = [];
    carIndexes.forEach((index) => {
      makes.push(filteredCars[index].attrs.car_make);
    });
    return makes.map((x, y) => <option key={y}>{x}</option>);
  };

  // On select filter the array
  const onSelect = e => {
    const newFiltered = [];
    const type = e.currentTarget.dataset.type;
    carIndexes.forEach((index) => {
      if (filteredCars[index].attrs[type] == e.currentTarget.value){
        newFiltered.push(filteredCars[index])
      };
    });
    setFilteredCars({...newFiltered})
  };

  return (
    <>
    <div>
      <select onChange={onSelect} data-type="body_type">
        <option selected>Pick Body</option>
        {bodySelects()}
      </select>
      <select onChange={onSelect} data-type="car_year">
        <option selected>Pick Year</option>
        {yearSelects()}
      </select>
      <select onChange={onSelect} data-type="car_make">
        <option selected>Pick Make</option>
        {makeSelects()}
      </select>
      <button onClick={() => setFilteredCars(cars)}>reset options</button>
    </div>
    <p>{filteredCars ? JSON.stringify(filteredCars) : ''}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time! the issue with this, is let's say i select 'Honda' then the options now become limited to 'Honda' so, i cant change it.

Comment: I was thinking about this more last night. Honestly I would then store the three filter options in individual arrays, and anytime one changes, just basically refilter the whole original array.

Rather than progressively filtering an increasingly reduced array, just have your master array, your filter options, filter it all, and set your new array to the result

Comment: so here's what i did... i have something like ```const [jsonList, setJsonList] = useState([publishprops.jsonData])``` and every time i filter, i add to that state like so: ```setJsonList(jsonList => [...jsonList, UpdateJson(allprops)]);``` with variations obviously, but in general, it's an array of arrays :) thanks!